# Using Navicat to create a Key on 2 column

Tags: mysql, sql, navicat

I can create a Primary Key using Navicat in the `Design Table` section of the software. However, I cannot seem to create a key on 2 columns, which in MySQL statements will be something like

```
CREATE TABLE casting(movieid INTEGER,
                 actorid INTEGER,
                 PRIMARY KEY (movieid, actorid)
                 )
```

Can it be done using the GUI in Navicat? Or must I write the query manually and run it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to click on the last cell .

[image]